# lazy evaluation python data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have the following code:

```
def get_data():
    return {"a": 1, "b":2}


def main():
    lazy_dic = lambda : get_data()
    a_value = lazy_dic()["a"]
    b_value = lazy_dic()["b"]
```

I want the `get_data()` function to be evaluated only once, and only the first time it is called.
when calling the assignment for b_value, I don't want the get_data function to be called again, but in this example, it is called twice.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I am looking for?

***Edit**

I write the code to show a simple example, In my use case, I want the dictionary only to be evaluated when it is accessed. (let's say the get_data takes the data from a database)

Comment: Why don't you do `lazy_dic = get_data()` instead of `lazy_dic = lambda : get_data()`?

Comment: With the current structure of your code sample, why don't you just do `lazy_dic = get_data()`? It does just that: create the data once, you can then use it as much as you want. If you meant something different, you should probably provide a more relevant code example.

Comment: @Timus because I want to evaluate the dictionary only when it is accessed.

Comment: You should probably make your real use case clearer, there might be different approaches (function call each time, or class property, with caching...)

Comment: you only want to access the get_data method one time? Like when you access second time it won't return anything?

Comment: @VikramChoudhary when accessing it a second time, it will already have the data

Comment: Check out [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: Last clarification when get_data is called second time it won't be able access "b" as u don't want get_data be called twice?

Comment: @VikramChoudhary I want lazy_dic()["b"] to return 2, but not accessing again get_data() function, but somewhat having it already.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this ([cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache))

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def get_data():
    return {"a":1, "b":2}
```

Here's a full example checking the status of the cache with [`cache_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache):

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def get_data():
    return {"a":1, "b":2}

get_data.cache_info()
# Out: CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=0, maxsize=None, currsize=0)

lazy_dic = lambda : get_data()

lazy_dic()["a"]
# Out: 1

get_data.cache_info()
# Out: CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=None, currsize=1)
```

Comment: In this way, the get_data() function is called every time I access the dictionary, I want to access it only once, and for the second time it would have the data from get_data()

Comment: OK, I see. Then one needs another solution, maybe some kind of caching?

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the solution for the problem.

```
def get_data():
   print("I got called only one time")
   return {"a":1,"b":2}

def main():
   lazy_dix = (lambda a: a)(get_data())
   output1 = lazy_dix["a"]
   output2 = lazy_dix["b"]
   print("output1 : ",output1,"\noutput2 : ",output2)

main()

#OUTPUT
I got called only one time
output1 :  1 
output2 :  2
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(lambda a: a)`?

Comment: "a" receives get_data() as an argument and returns the data after evaluating.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. `(lambda a: a)(get_data())` is just an overcomplicated way to write `get_data()`.

Comment: Why not just `lazy_dix = get_data()`?

Comment: Yes it's same, I thought you wanted to use lambda. Remove lambda code will run same ;). Is it the answer you wanted?

Comment: No u wanted to call get_data() only once. Your requirement is changing. bye.